# Access the current android activity

Tags: android, android-activity, java-native-interface, android-ndk

How can I access the current Android activity class?

I am using the necessitas framework (QT in Android). Basically, using the Android NDK an activity calls a QT application (.so). All runs fine. Now I am working on some bindings to access the GPS from the QT application. From some java examples that access the GPS I saw that the most vital part is to allow access to the GPS service:

LocationManager lm;
lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Here getSystemService is a method of class activity. Because I am using the JNI inside the QT application I need to access the current activity that is running my QT application, so I can call the function getSystemService.

So the question is. How do I get the current activity where my QT application is running from?

Comment: why do you need to access the gps like that?

Comment: Where are you trying to make this call at?  If you have an instance of 'Context', you should be able to call getSystemService(String)

Comment: can you show some code? your question is a bit confuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by passing the current application (running my QT application) to my QT application using JNI's RegisterNatives().

Carlos.

Comment: I also want to be run an existing android project on QT. I am new in this line. So I want to be run a small android project on QT. How it is possible. Can you give me some sample code...?

Comment: @QLands:  I am doing the same just with the bluetooth adapter. Could you please elaborate how you were able to get the context as I did not understand this answer. A short code example would also help clarify. Thanks.